# Raspberry Pi bluetooth not detected by any device and also not detecting any devices around it. Details below

Tags: pi-4, bluetooth

I am using the latest version of Raspberry Pi (Buster) on a Raspberry Pi 4,2Gb model. After a fresh flash and boot up, I clicked on the raspberry pi default Bluetooth > clicked "make discoverable" and "Add device". But no device is able to detect the raspberry and vice versa. Screenshot below:

[image]

After some research I see, further packages is needed, so the customary:

> sudo apt update and sudo apt upgrade

I installed the following Bluetooth packages:

> sudo apt install bluetooth pi-bluetooth bluez blueman

After a reboot, I am getting a new error, screenshot below:
[image]

Investigating the Dbus permission issue:

I traversed to the directory "/usr/lib/dbus-1.0" and found the file "dbus-daemon-launch-helper". The file has the following permissions by default:

[image]

The permissions look fine, the user group has the SUID bit permission set correctly, so am unsure why I am getting the Dbus permission error.

I have tried fresh install of Raspian multiple times and tried to bluetooth connect via iPhone/android and even from a old Nokia phone.

Bottom-line, a fresh out of box Raspbian having Bluetooth error is suprising, any help to resolve will be helpful. I just need to pair the Raspberry to my android phone so I can use "Bluedot" to control my Pi.

Answer (score 1):

Doing a fresh install, `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt full-upgrade` is what they [recommend](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/raspbian/updating.md) now.

For Bluedot you shouldn't need to do the `Add Device` on the RPi. Are you following the instructions at https://bluedot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pairpiandroid.html ?

Try using the [using the command line](https://bluedot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pairpiandroid.html#using-the-command-line) method to see if that makes a difference.

To get more debug information have separate terminals open with the following running:

- `bluetootctl`
- `journalctl -f -u bluetooth`
- `sudo busctl monitor org.bluez`
- `sudo btmon`